# calculating the mean by another variable's categories in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an example of a dataset like this:

```
id <-       c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4,4, 5,5,5,5, 6,6,6, 7, 8,8)
item.id <-  c(1,1,2, 1,1,1 ,1,1, 1,2, 1,2,2,2, 1,1,1, 1, 1,2)
sequence <- c(1,2,1, 1,2,3, 1,2, 1,1, 1,1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1, 1,1)
score <-    c(0,0,0, 0,0,1, 1,0, 1,1, 1,0,1,1, 0,0,0, 1, 0,1)
category <- c(2,2,2, 3,3,3, 1,1, 3,3, 1,1,1,1, 4,4,4, 2, 3,3)

data <- data.frame("id"=id, "item.id"=item.id, "sequence"=sequence, "score"=score, "category"=category)
> data
   id item.id sequence score category
1   1       1        1     0        2
2   1       1        2     0        2
3   1       2        1     0        2
4   2       1        1     0        3
5   2       1        2     0        3
6   2       1        3     1        3
7   3       1        1     1        1
8   3       1        2     0        1
9   4       1        1     1        3
10  4       2        1     1        3
11  5       1        1     1        1
12  5       2        1     0        1
13  5       2        2     1        1
14  5       2        3     1        1
15  6       1        1     0        4
16  6       1        2     0        4
17  6       1        3     0        4
18  7       1        1     1        2
19  8       1        1     0        3
20  8       2        1     1        3
```

`id` represents persons, `item.id` is for questions. `sequence` is for the attempt to change the response, and the `score` is the score of the item, `category` is the category each student falls in.

What I want to do is to grab the maximum sequence number for each `id` per `item.id`, then calculate the mean score of the maximum sequence value for each `category`. I was able to complete the first step but could not figure out how to take the cross tab of the mean of the maximum sequence number per `category`.

```
library(dplyr)
    data %>%
      group_by(id,item.id) %>%
      summarize(max.seq = max(sequence))
    # A tibble: 12 x 3
    # Groups:   id [?]
          id item.id max.seq
       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
     1     1       1       2
     2     1       2       1
     3     2       1       3
     4     3       1       2
     5     4       1       1
     6     4       2       1
     7     5       1       1
     8     5       2       3
     9     6       1       3
    10     7       1       1
    11     8       1       1
    12     8       2       1
```

The result of the second step should be:

```
category           1     2    3    4 
mean(max(seq))     2    1.33 1.4   3
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the category value into the summary table.  Since the category value is constant for each id, item.id combination using the mean in the summary function is one way.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(id,item.id) %>%
  summarize(cat=mean(category), max.seq = max(sequence)) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% summarize(mean(max.seq))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
    cat `mean(max.seq)`
  <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1            2   
2     2            1.33
3     3            1.4 
4     4            3
```

My calculations are slightly different from yours, please double check my method before accepting.

Comment: your calculation is correct. thanks so much for the explained solution :)